Is it possible to facilitate an NFC p2p on Android without Android Beam or HCE?
I am trying to create an app that swaps contact information between two phones using NFC, much like Apple's NameDrop feature for iPhones. This requires an NFC p2p connection, as far as I know.
I tried looking for examples that didn't use the Android Beam API, but I found nothing. This means all examples that there were won't work on Android 14+, which is undesirable. I did also find old posts on stack overflow regarding this challenge, but none of the solutions appear to work now that the p2p communication is deprecated on Android. Of other ones I have found, they rely on HCE, which means it is only a one-way connection, and one device has to decide to be the host. This would make the tapping of devices impossible, as it would be impossible to determine who should be the host as far as I'm concerned.
